# Python recursion test in PyCharm - Process finished with exit code 139

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, recursion, pycharm

**System:** Ubuntu 14

**IDE:** PyCharm Community Edition 3.1.1

**Python:** 2.7.6

Algorithm with recurrent call:

```
def fibonacci_dynamic(n):
    if n == 0:
       return 0
    if n == 1:
       return 1
    computed_values = {1: 1, 2: 1}
    return memoize(n, computed_values)


def memoize(n, computed_values):
    if n in computed_values:
        return computed_values[n]
    #recurrent call
    computed_values[n - 1] = memoize(n - 1, computed_values)
    computed_values[n - 2] = memoize(n - 2, computed_values)
    new_value = computed_values[n - 1] + computed_values[n - 2]
    computed_values[n] = new_value
    return new_value
```

Test:

```
from unittest import TestCase
from first.fib.fibonacci import fibonacci_dynamic
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(40000)


class TestFibonacci_dynamic_param(TestCase):

    def test_fibonacci_dynamic_26175(self):
        result = fibonacci_dynamic(26175)
        self.assertIsNotNone(result)
```

Value in test is intended. Around value `26175` test sometimes pass but sometimes it is terminated with message:
`Process finished with exit code 139`
I understand that test result somehow depends from hardware resources but I'm looking for more precise answer from stackoverflow seniors :)

Comment: Remove `sys.setrecursionlimit(40000)` and you wont get that error anymore. It is caused because the call stack is overflowing. (Hint: if you ever need to call `setrecursionlimit` there's something wrong in your code).

Comment: I need this because without this recursion limit i reached and I get error 'RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded'

Comment: You have 3 choices: 1) Live with the `RuntimeException` which you can catch and try to handle, 2) Use `setrecursionlimit` to avoid the exception but get a segmentation fault instead (with bigger inputs), which cannot be handled 3) Fix the implementation of your code to avoid the big number of recursion calls and compute much bigger fibonacci numbers.

Comment: Dynamic programming is *all* about avoiding repeating solving subproblems more than once. Now, do you think your function achieve this? Do you think the order in which you perform the recursive call into `memoize` matters?

Comment: Good point - this problem came up when I was in the middle of creating presentation about optimisation - so that why this algorithm is not optimised - I tried get results for comparison with iterating approach :)

Answer (score -1):

You can use non-recursive algorithm to calculate Fibonacci numbers

```
class FibonacciNumbers(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._fib = [0, 1, 1] #first three fibonacci numbers

    def get(self, n):
        if n < len(self._fib):
            return self._fib[n]
        for i in xrange(len(self._fib), n+1):
            self._fib.append(self._fib[i-1] + self._fib[i-2])
        return self._fib[-1]


fib = FibonacciNumbers()
print fib.get(0)
print fib.get(1000)
```

Or use the formula: